# Android WebView Not Resolving Server Name Like Chrome

Tags: android, android-webview

In a `WebView`, in our Android app, we are trying to detect that a server can’t be reached. It is working in Chrome on Android but not in a `WebView` in our Android app.

**In Chrome:**

- I run our website in Chrome on an Android phone (Nexus 4, Android
  5.1.1; Nexus 5x, Android 7.1.2) while on our internal network
- Switch to our guest network, which doesn’t have access to the website server
- Select a link to another page on our server
- In my desktop’s Chrome’s device inspection’s console, I immediately see the
  `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error and we can display a message to the
  user.

**In a WebView:**

- I run our website in a WebView in our Android app
- Switch to the guest network
- Select a link to another page on our server
- Nothing happens for a while (about a minute) and then I see, in my desktop’s Chrome’s device inspection’s console, a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error for the https:// request for the next page.
- This is not consistent behavior but it fails in this manner around 75% of the time

I’m trying to understand why Chrome tried to resolve the server’s name but the `WebView` did not so we then have to wait for the connection to timeout and then display a message to the user?